# Issue with Twig file paths and extending a template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

So I'm trying to extend a layout, and I have the directory structure as such: `../src/views/base.html.twig`.

I'm using the code examples right from [the documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html), but I have some issue with the file path that I just can't resolve.

In a child template in the same folder named `layout.html.twig`, I have `{% extends "base.html.twig" %}`, but it doesn't do anything. I've tried every possible path combination, but nothing works.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions on that page are for the standalone engine as opposed to as part of the Symfony Framework. For info on the Framework version see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#template-inheritance-and-layouts.

If it is in `app/Resources/views/` then you should use `::base.html.twig`.

If it is in a bundle like `Acme\RandomBundle` then you should use `AcmeRandomBundle::base.html.twig`.